# How to add property to object through ng-model in html page in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a object I have iterated using ng-repeat and while iterating I want to add each field to another object through ng-model.

```
//html 

<div ng-repeat="field in forms.fields track by $index">
    <span ng-if="field.type=='textbox'">
    <span style="width:115px;text-transform: capitalize" class="col-lg-5">{{field.Name}}</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 172px;padding-left: 20px;display: inline-block;" ng-class="{mystyle:field.Name.$invalid}" id="inp_{{$index}}" ng-model="inputfields.{{field.Name}}">{{field.Name}}<br>
</span></div>
```

In the above code i want to assign field.Name as a property to input field which is declared as a `$scope.inputfield={} in js file`. So i am getting an error as

```
 Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{inputfield.field.Name}}] starting at [{inputfield.field.Name}}].
```

So can anyone solve this please.

Comment: Try `inputfields[field.Name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
ng-model="inputfields[field.Name]"
```

Answer (score 1):

use with array notation to get the property of the object

```
ng-model="inputfields[field.Name]"
```

instead of

```
ng-model="inputfields.{{field.Name}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inputfields.{{field.Name}} is invalid expression assignment.
```

You can assign fidlename to inputfields using `ng-model="inputfields[field.Name]"`

for more detail refer this link : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign